# Electron-package not including all source files

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an electron app which runs with no problems when using `electron www` from the command line, however when i use electron-package to build a standalone binary, the built binary produces a console error as it cannot find certain front-end libs (angularMoment being one of them). Electron-package also fails to include other folders which contain the HTML templates for the app.

The project folder looks like this:

```
/electron
    /www
        /app
        /css
        /img
        /js
        /node_modules
        - index.html
        - main.js
        - package.json
```

I am running `electron-package` from within the `www` folder and the process completes without errors however as mentioned earlier certain folders within the `lib` folder get missed off / ignored.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the open source [electron-forge](https://electronforge.io/) to kickstart, build, and run your app. It has saved me heaps of time configuring, debugging, etc.!

Answer (score 0):

When developing, did you install angular-moment by using the `npm install angular-moment --save` command?

Comment: no, all of the front-end libs are installed using bower. Some of which *are* included in the electron-package. I just cant work out why it includes some but not others.

Comment: As long as you use the `--save` parameter it should generally retain it and use it in packaging. Did you manually move the lib or something like that?